# Not able to apply and save Job in Jenkins. Getting Error "A problem occurred while processing the request."

Tags: jenkins

I am Using Jenkins under tomcat and getting error

> A problem occurred while processing the request.

every time when trying to apply changes in the Job. Not able to apply and save the changes in the Job.

Comment: I recall it has something to do with cache and session in your browser due that Jenkins stores a lot per request. So if you could clear them for your browser you should be able to save and apply your changes.